# store mysql data in array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a doubt. Why can't we store the elements of mysql_fetch_row in an array and then use it later in the code?

For example, this bunch of code gives unexpected waiting time error.

```
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$n=mysql_num_rows($result);
$a=array();
$a[$i]=array();
for ($i=o; $i<$n; $i++)
{
    $r=mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $a[$i][0]=$r[0];
    $a[$i][1]=$r[1];
}
echo $a[0][1];
echo $a[0][0];
```

Answer (score 1):

try to change this

```
    $r=mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

to

```
   $r=mysql_fetch_num($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Better way is to use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` function.

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$a = array();
if ($result !== false) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $a[] = $row;
    }
}

var_dump($a);
```

And BTW in `for` loop declaration you have `o` instead of `0`!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)